# Time until midnight between two date and time columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need help with my query to calculate the time until midnight between two date and time columns
break down by day

This is the main table:

| ID | Start_Time | End_time | DateDiff |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 32221 | 01-01-2022 13:10:00 | 01-03-2022 13:10:00 | 2880 |

My query:

```
 
SELECT
    start_time.ID,
    start_time.Date_Time AS Start_time,
    end_time.Date_Time AS End_time,
    DATEDIFF(minute, start_time.Date_Time, end_time.Date_Time) AS DateDiff
FROM 
    Main
```

what I  need is similar to this:

| ID | Date_start | End_time | DateDiff |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 32221 | 01-01-2022 13:10:00 | 01-01-2022 23:59:59 | 654 |
| 32221 | 01-02-2022 00:00:00 | 01-02-2022 23:59:59 | 1440 |
| 32221 | 01-03-2022 00:00:00 | 01-03-2022 13:10:00 | 781 |

how i can do that?

Comment: You just want to calculate the time till midnight for one of your dates?  You can do DateDiff and have end time be midnight hard coded value (or built in code)
Select DateDiff(minute, YourDateToFindTillMidnight, xx/xx/xxxx 0:00:00)  where xxx is your date

Comment: @Brad I need the DATEDIFF grouped by the date for example if the start date is Sunday and end date is Tuesday i need to see each day in separate row with it's own DATEDIFF

Comment: It looks like one of your dates is always midnight so your problem is more accurately described as "time between two dates" - which is just datediff. Probably your description needs a little more focus here as "time until midnight between two dates" is not very clear - that sounds like a midpoint but there would be two answers, time from the first date and time from the second date.

Comment: @topsail I need the DATEDIFF grouped by the date for example if the start date is Sunday and end date is Tuesday i need to see each day in separate row with it's own DATEDIFF. that's why i need midnight

Comment: Ah. Funny I think I faced this same problem once before ... but whether or not I had a good solution or not I can't remember. I believe I was only worrying about the case where midnight boundary was crossed a single time though, not over several days.

Comment: A calendar table would really help with a problem like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through the times, always adding the time untill midnight, untill your 'start_time + 1 day' is bigger than your end_time.

The below code can be run directly in SQL (mind the date notation, my SQL is in united states notation, so if yours is in Europe this will give you back results for 3 months instead of 3 days);

```
DECLARE @start_time datetime2 = '01/01/2022 13:00:00';
DECLARE @end_time datetime2 = '03/01/2022 14:00:00';
DECLARE @daily_end_time datetime2=NULL;
DECLARE @Table Table (start_time datetime2, end_time datetime2, diff nvarchar(8));
DECLARE @diff_minutes_start int = DATEDIFF(MINUTE,@start_time,DateDiff(day,0,dateadd(day,1,@start_time)));
DECLARE @diff_minutes_end int = DATEDIFF(minute,@end_time,DateDiff(day,0,dateadd(day,1,@end_time)))
SET @daily_end_time = DATEADD(mi,@diff_minutes_start,@start_time)

WHILE @daily_end_time < @end_time
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @Table (start_time,end_time,diff) 
    VALUES (
    @start_time,
    CASE WHEN DATEADD(day,1,@daily_end_time) > @end_time THEN @end_time ELSE 
@daily_end_time END,
CASE WHEN DATEADD(day,1,@daily_end_time) > @end_time THEN @diff_minutes_end ELSE 
@diff_minutes_start END )
  SET @daily_end_time = DATEADD(mi,@diff_minutes_start,@start_time)
SET @start_time = DATEADD(mi,1,@daily_end_time);
select @diff_minutes_start  = 


DATEDIFF(MINUTE,@start_time,DateDiff(day,0,dateadd(day,1,@start_time)));
    select @diff_minutes_end  = DATEDIFF(minute,@end_time,DateDiff(day,0,dateadd(day,1,@end_time)))
    END
    SELECT * FROM @Table
```

And the results:

[image]

Comment: Note one difference in my code; for the last day you are again getting the diff until midnight, so you'll need to add another case statement or IF in there, that for the last loop you compare start and end, instead of start and midnight.

Answer (score 1):

You may use a recursive `CTE` as the following:

```
With CTE As
(
  Select ID, Start_Time, End_time, DATEADD(Second, -1, DATEADD(Day, DATEDIFF(Day,0, Start_Time), 1)) et
  From main
  Union All
  Select C.ID, DATEADD(Second, 1, C.et), C.End_time, DATEADD(Day, 1, C.et)
  From CTE C Join main T
  On C.ID = T.ID
  Where DATEADD(Second, 1, C.et) <= C.End_time 
 )
Select ID, Start_Time, 
       Case When End_Time <= et Then End_Time Else et End As End_Time,
       DATEDIFF(Minute, Start_Time, DATEADD(Second, 1, Case When End_Time <= et Then End_Time Else et End)) As [DateDiff]
From CTE
Order By ID, Start_Time
```

See a demo with extended data sample from [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=91a78cde3aad1c585dbe0d35b5c8d52e).

Answer (score 1):

You can also solve this with a tally table, using the expanded (to show different cases) sample data

| ID | StartTime | EndTime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 32221 | 2022-01-01 13:10:00 | 2022-01-03 13:10:00 |
| 32222 | 2022-02-02 10:10:00 | 2022-02-02 17:10:00 |
| 32223 | 2022-03-03 19:10:00 | 2022-03-04 08:10:00 |
| 32224 | 2022-04-04 19:10:00 | 2022-04-08 08:10:00 |

and the code

```
with cteSampleData as ( --Enter some sample data, include spans of 0, 1, and >1 days
    SELECT * --Note that we need CONVERT to make sure the dates are treated as datetime not string!
    FROM (VALUES(32221, CONVERT(datetime2(0), '01-01-2022 13:10:00'), CONVERT(datetime2(0), '01-03-2022 13:10:00') )
        , (32222, '02-02-2022 10:10:00', '02-02-2022 17:10:00') 
        , (32223, '03-03-2022 19:10:00', '03-04-2022 08:10:00') 
        , (32224, '04-04-2022 19:10:00', '04-08-2022 08:10:00') 
    ) as Samp(ID, StartTime, EndTime)
), cteWithControl as ( --Add some fields to make testing cledarer - you could do this as part of a subsequent step instead
    SELECT * 
        , CONVERT(date, StartTime) as StartDate , CONVERT(date, EndTime) as EndDate
        , DATEDIFF(day, StartTime , EndTime) as DiffDays
        --, DATEDIFF(day, CONVERT(date, StartTime) , CONVERT(date, EndTime)) as DiffDays
    FROM cteSampleData
), cteTally as ( --Get a list of integers to represent days, assume nothing lasts longer than a year
    SELECT top 365 ROW_NUMBER() over (ORDER BY name) as Tally 
    FROM sys.objects --just a table we know has over 300 rows, look up tally tables for other generation methods
)--The real work begins below, partition the data into "same day" and "multi-day" spans
, cteSet as (
    SELECT ID, StartTime, EndTime, DiffDays, 1 as DayNumber
    FROM cteWithControl WHERE DiffDays = 0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ID --For multi-day, cross with the tally table and treat first and last days special
        , CASE WHEN T.Tally = 1 THEN StartTime --For the first day the start time is the real time
            ELSE DATEADD (day, T.Tally - 1, startdate) END as StartTime --Otherwise it's the start of the day
        , CASE WHEN T.Tally = DiffDays + 1 THEN EndTime --For the last day the end is the real end
            ELSE DATEADD (second, -1, CONVERT(DATETIME2(0), DATEADD (day, T.Tally, startdate))) 
            END as EndTime --otherwise 1 second less than the next day
        , DiffDays, Tally as DayNumber
    FROM cteWithControl as D CROSS JOIN cteTally as T
    WHERE DiffDays > 0 AND T.Tally <= D.DiffDays + 1
)--Now we display the results and calculate the length (in minutes) of each span
SELECT *
    , DATEDIFF(MINUTE, StartTime, EndTime) as DateDiff 
FROM cteSet
ORDER BY ID, DayNumber
```

we get the output

| ID | StartTime | EndTime | DiffDays | DayNumber | DateDiff |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 32221 | 2022-01-01 13:10:00 | 2022-01-01 23:59:59 | 2 | 1 | 649 |
| 32221 | 2022-01-02 00:00:00 | 2022-01-02 23:59:59 | 2 | 2 | 1439 |
| 32221 | 2022-01-03 00:00:00 | 2022-01-03 13:10:00 | 2 | 3 | 790 |
| 32222 | 2022-02-02 10:10:00 | 2022-02-02 17:10:00 | 0 | 1 | 420 |
| 32223 | 2022-03-03 19:10:00 | 2022-03-03 23:59:59 | 1 | 1 | 289 |
| 32223 | 2022-03-04 00:00:00 | 2022-03-04 08:10:00 | 1 | 2 | 490 |
| 32224 | 2022-04-04 19:10:00 | 2022-04-04 23:59:59 | 4 | 1 | 289 |
| 32224 | 2022-04-05 00:00:00 | 2022-04-05 23:59:59 | 4 | 2 | 1439 |
| 32224 | 2022-04-06 00:00:00 | 2022-04-06 23:59:59 | 4 | 3 | 1439 |
| 32224 | 2022-04-07 00:00:00 | 2022-04-07 23:59:59 | 4 | 4 | 1439 |
| 32224 | 2022-04-08 00:00:00 | 2022-04-08 08:10:00 | 4 | 5 | 490 |